# Websockets - Sec-WebSocket-Accept mismatch

Tags: c++, websocket

I'm writing the websocket server on C++ and having a problem with calculating the Sec-WebSocket-Accept key. I've tested sha1 and it generates the right value (I've taken the string from wikipedia example and got the same hash) and I also found the online base64 converter to test the second part, and it seems working right. But as I can see from other issues, my string is too long.

```
  std::string secKey =  readHeader(buffer,n,"Sec-WebSocket-Key");
  std::string magic = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";

  secKey.append(magic);
  unsigned char hash[20];
  char hexstring[41];

  sha1::calc(secKey.c_str(),secKey.length(),hash);
  sha1::toHexString(hash,hexstring);
  std::string encoded = base64_encode(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(hexstring) ,strlen(hexstring));
```

For secKey = "4aRdFZG5uYrEUw8dsNLW6g==" I get encoded value "YTYwZWRlMjQ4NWFhNzJiYmRjZTQ5ODI4NjUwMWNjNjE1YTM0MzZkNg=="

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can skip the toHexString line and base64 encode the 20 byte hash instead.

```
sha1::calc(secKey.c_str(),secKey.length(),hash);
std::string encoded = base64_encode(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(hash), 20);
```

That's what my [C++ server](https://github.com/openhome/ohNet/blob/master/OpenHome/Net/Device/Upnp/DviServerWebSocket.cpp) does and handshakes complete successfully.

Comment: @Nikita, glad it works.  If you're happy with my answer, can you accept it (the green tick under the vote up/down buttons)?

Comment: I tried to do that yesterday, but I don't have enough reputation yet, sorry =)

Comment: I think you should be able to do that.  You'd need to click on the outline of a tick below the up/down arrows.  Accepting answers increases your reputation so it'd be a bit unfair if a low initial rep prevented you doing this :-)

Comment: My mistake! I was clicking on up arrow. Accepted now, thanks!)